# JQuery .click event won't turn back on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a panel (div) that slides in and out of my nav bar. Right now, it'll open and close once just fine but then it won't respond to clicks anymore.

```
$('.work-link').mouseover(function(){
    if($('.work-link').css('left') === '0px')
    {
        $('.work-link').off('click');
    }
    else if($('.work-link').css('left') === '-750px')
    {
        $('.work-link').on('click');
    };
});

$('.work-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.work-link').animate({left: '0px'}, 600);
    $('.work-link').css('cursor', 'default');
    $('.sort-container').animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 800);
    $('.exit-sort').fadeIn(600);
    $('.port-type').animate({marginRight: '140px'}, 600);
    $('.port-type').text("CLICK THE X TO CLOSE").fadeIn();
});

$('.exit-sort').on('click',function(){
    $('.work-link').animate({left: '-750px'}, 600);
    $('.work-link').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('.sort-container').animate({marginLeft: '-750px'}, 700);
    $('.exit-sort').fadeOut(600);
    $('.port-type').animate({marginRight: '70px'}, 600);
    $('.port-type').text("SORT THIS PORTFOLIO BY TYPE").fadeIn();
});
```

I figured the problem has to do with how I used the .on() and .off() events but I don't know how else to approach it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for your code please ?

Comment: have you created `work-link` adn `exit-sort` dynamically in your page?

Comment: It would be much easier to just leave the click event bound and just set some flag in your code to ignore it when you need to.

Comment: Such as `$('.work-link').on('click', function(){ if($(this).css('left') != '0px') {`

Comment: Tried defining click handler as named function `function clickHandler(){
    $('.work-link').animate({left: '0px'}, 600);..}`, reattach handler at `else if` statement `$('.work-link').on('click', clickHandler);` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this : instead of having mouseover handler just use if conditions in click handler as shown below so that you don't have to on / off click handlers again and again.

**NOTE**:- You should use `$(this)` instead of `$('.work-link')` which will be extra load on script. `$(this)` is the object of clicked element.

```
$('.work-link').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).css('left') === '0px')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if($(this).css('left') === '-750px')
    {
       $('.work-link').animate({left: '0px'}, 600);
       $('.work-link').css('cursor', 'default');
       $('.sort-container').animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 800);
       $('.exit-sort').fadeIn(600);
       $('.port-type').animate({marginRight: '140px'}, 600);
       $('.port-type').text("CLICK THE X TO CLOSE").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Who has downvoted without any reason, OP has accepted the answer though. People are insane here who just want to downvote for the sake of decreasing others points .... oh come on

Answer (score 0):

The click eventhandler is discarded when you call `.off()`. To turn it back on, you have to call the `.on()` function again with the event callback (as if you are calling for the first time).

That is, your `.mouseover()` call needs to be changed like this:

```
$('.work-link').mouseover(function(){
    if($('.work-link').css('left') === '0px')
    {
        $('.work-link').off('click');
    }
    else if($('.work-link').css('left') === '-750px')
    {
        $('.work-link').on('click', function(){
            $('.work-link').animate({left: '-750px'}, 600);
            $('.work-link').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('.sort-container').animate({marginLeft: '-750px'}, 700);
            $('.exit-sort').fadeOut(600);
            $('.port-type').animate({marginRight: '70px'}, 600);
            $('.port-type').text("SORT THIS PORTFOLIO BY TYPE").fadeIn();
        });
    };
});
```

PS: Validate syntax/typos as I couldn't test your code.